Why Can’t Siri spell my child’s name
My son‘s name is Charlie, it is a very common name. But when I use voice to text Siri never adds the E at the end. I have tried adding the phonetic spelling in his contact, that does not work. Open to other ideas please

You might want to adjust the phonetic spelling to emphasize the ending, like "Charlee" or "Charley."

If you're using voice text, you can spell your child's name, but it'll be in all caps. That's what I do when there are things that I can't say correctly in voice texting.
